# How do I get values as strings from a specific key in a JSON key-value pair in VB.net?

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, visual-studio, key-value

I get a JSON file (about 1300 lines) from an API HTTP GET request . Here's a small example excerpt:

```
{
      "platformId": 3,
      "platformName": "pc",
      "platformNameLong": "PC"
}
```

I use this data and convert it to an object (Source is the result of the API request):

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
```

,

```
Dim Data As New Statistics
    Data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Statistics)(source)
```

and

```
Public Class Statistics
    Public Property platformId As Integer
    Public Property platformName As String
    Public Property platformNameLong As String
End Class
```

and it works and lets me use this object later link in the following example.

```
Label1.Content = Data.platformNameLong
```

**I now got a JSON part like that:**

```
{
 "lifeTimeStats": [
    {
      "key": "Score",
      "value": "7,919,327"
    },
    {
      "key": "Matches Played",
      "value": "20105"
    ]
}
```

How am I able to get the value from a **specific key** (in the **value-key pair** part of the JSON) into my object
(or as a string value)?

Note: Some labels in the JSON have the same name as keys in the value-key part; is there any way of just getting the values for keys within "lifeTimeStats"?

Example: What if I want to get the "value" where "key": "Matches Played", in this case "20105"?

Comment: YourSomething = Jobject.Parse(YourJSON)("platformId") and you get a 3

Comment: @CruleD But is this also working in the key-value JSON part?

Comment: @Jul79 could you please update your post with sample input key and expected output to your post so it helps us to provide working answer.

Comment: Then you do it with ("lifeTimeStats")(x)("key") and ("lifeTimeStats")(x)("value"), where xis index of the array.

Comment: @sam Done: "What if I want to get the "value" where "key": "Matches Played", in this case "20105"?"

Comment: @CruleD How do I do that?

Comment: It's still ("lifeTimeStats")(x)("key"), if you look my previous answers on json all should be clear.

Comment: Ah ok I just didn't understand that I have to use the raw data but it's working. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Does something like below work (please replace serializedJsonString with your json variable):

Option# 1:

```
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(serializedJsonString)
    Dim jsonArray As JArray = jsonObject("lifeTimeStats")                   

    If jsonArray IsNot Nothing Then

        For Each o As JObject In jsonArray.Children(Of JObject)()
            If o("key").ToString() <> key Then Continue For
            Console.WriteLine(o("value").ToString())
            Exit For
        Next
    End If
```

**Option#2:**  Using SelectToken as mentioned [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm#SelectTokenLINQ).

```
Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(serializedJsonString)
Dim jsonArray As JArray = jsonObject("lifeTimeStats")                   

If jsonArray IsNot Nothing Then

    For Each item As JObject In jsonArray
        If item.SelectToken("key").ToString <> key Then Continue For
        Console.WriteLine(item.SelectToken("value").ToString)
        Exit For            
     Next
End If
```